# Is it possible to return a struct array from a function?

Tags: c

This is my first real coding class and I may be going the wrong way here, but for a project in C programming class I need to write a function to read in various numbers from a file and separate them into categories: coefficients and exponentials. I think I have that part done already, however to use the contents of the numbers I have read I'm attempting to pass an array of struct from a function to the main so I can use the contents. The code below is what I have now, and it does not give me any errors, however when I access the array in the main function, it is empty except for the first value. Is there something I can change to make this work? Or a better way of going about this?

Any help is appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct exponential
{
    float coef;
    int expo;
    struct exponential *ptr_exp;
}EXPO;

EXPO** input_poly(EXPO *ex_array[], FILE *finput);

int main()
{
    FILE *finput;
    finput=fopen("cp7_in.txt","r");
    EXPO *ptr_array[2];
    EXPO **ptr, *ptr1, *ptr2, **ptraddress;
    ptr=(input_poly(ptr_array, finput));
}


EXPO** input_poly(EXPO *ptr_array[], FILE *finput)
{
    int count, string_size, offset1, offset2, offset3, offset4;
    char expo_string[64];
    char *expo_ptr, *string1, *string2;
    EXPO *ptr1, *ptr2;
    string1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(expo_string)+1);
    string2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(expo_string)+1);
    for(count=0;(fgets(expo_string,64,finput)>0)&&(count<2);count++)
    {
        if(count==0)
        {
            strcpy(string1,expo_string);
        }
        if(count==1)
        {
            strcpy(string2,expo_string);
        }
    }
    EXPO ex_array1[(sizeof(string1)/2)];
    EXPO ex_array2[(sizeof(string2)/2)];
    count=0;
    string_size=(sizeof(string1)/2);
    offset1=0;
    offset2=0;
    offset3=0;
    offset4=0;
    while(count<string_size)
    {
        sscanf((string1+offset2),"%e %d %n",&(ex_array1[count]).coef,&(ex_array1[count]).expo,&offset1);
        sscanf((string2+offset4),"%e %d %n",&(ex_array2[count]).coef,&(ex_array2[count]).expo,&offset3);
        (ex_array1[count]).ptr_exp=&(ex_array1[count+1]);
        (ex_array2[count]).ptr_exp=&(ex_array2[count+1]);
        count++;
        offset2+=offset1;
        offset4+=offset3;
    }
    ptr1=ex_array1;
    ptr2=ex_array2;
    ptr_array[0]=ptr1;
    ptr_array[1]=ptr2;
    free(string1);
    free(string2);
    return ptr_array;
 }
```

Comment: The code is very hard to follow, why do you return a pointer to a pointer to `EXPO` ? also EXPO look like a linked list but you use an array of EXPO instead. You might need to clean up your code a little bit. Also check return values of `fopen` `malloc` `fgets` `sscanf` ( I am probably mmissing a few )

Comment: My apologies, I've never written a program that requires anything complicated until now. The way I have it is the only way I understand C code at the moment. One of the requirements for the project is that I need to use a function to read the numbers from the file, but I don't know how to get them into the main function.

Comment: You can't return pointers pointing at local objects and that's that.

Comment: from what I understood from your code, [I tried to simplify it](https://pastebin.com/bV6pPtf1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't return an array of structs from a function. From [function declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration):

```
In the declaration grammar of a function declaration, the type-specifier 
sequence, possibly modified by the declaration, designates the return type 
(which may be any type other than array or function type)...
```

The return type returned by a function can't be an array, so you can't return an array from a function.
The common way around this, is to return a pointer to the first array element:

```
struct arr_s {
    int arr_member;
};

struct arr_s *function_that_returns_array_of_5_ints(void) {
    static struct arr_s array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    return arr; // 'Array to pointer conversion'
}

void some_function(void) {
    struct arr_s *arr = function_that_returns_array_of_5_ints();
    printf("%d\n", arr[3].arr_member);
}
```

The way `arr[3].arr_member` works is because `arr[3]` translates to `*(arr + 3)` and because of [pointer arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic):

```
- If the pointer P points at an element of an array with index I, then
  - P+N and N+P are pointers that point at an element of the same array with index I+N
```

Now, to your code, look at this fragments, I've added some comments:

```
// ptr_array is declared in main and passed to this function,
// so it's storage duration is longer then this function
EXPO** input_poly(EXPO *ptr_array[], FILE *finput)
{
    ...
    // these variables are placed on stack, they have automatic storage duration
    EXPO ex_array1[(sizeof(string1)/2)];
    EXPO ex_array2[(sizeof(string2)/2)];
    ....
    ptr1=ex_array1;
    ptr2=ex_array2;
    ptr_array[0]=ptr1; // = ex_array1
    ptr_array[1]=ptr2; // = ex_array2
    ...
    return ptr_array; // the variables ex_array1 and ex_array2 stop existing here,
    // yet you return pointers to them in ptr_array[0] and ptr_array[1].
    // the memory allocated for ex_arrays does not exists after return
}
```

`ex_array1` and `ex_array2` are variables with [atomatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). What that means, is:

```
automatic storage duration. The storage is allocated when the block 
in which the object was declared is entered and deallocated when it 
is exited by any means (goto, return, reaching the end).
```

(They are not VLAs because `(sizeof(string1)/2)` is a constant expression. Anyway, the following still would hold true). As the memory allocated for variables `ex_array1` and `ex_array2` cease to exist after returning from `input_poly` function, you return a pointer to nonexistent memory (storage which has been deallocated), you can't no longer access ex_arrays.
Also pay attention to the [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator. `sizeof(expo_string)` is equal to `sizeof(char[60])` is equal to 60. But `sizeof(string1)` is equal to `sizeof(char*)`, so on 64-bit machine may be equal to 8 (may be not, this is machine dependent), so actually in place `EXPO ex_array1[(sizeof(string1)/2)];` you are actually doing `EXPO ex_array1[4];` and also `string_size = 4;`, probably that wasn't the intent.
The solution is to use malloc or to declare ex_arrays with static storage duration, either declare them 'globally' outside `input_poly` function or use `static` keyword. I think, the best you can do is:

```
  EXPO *ex_array1 = malloc(sizeof(string1)/2);
  EXPO *ex_array2 = malloc(sizeof(string2)/2);
```

or i can guess you really wanted to do smth like:

```
  string_size = strlen(string1)/2; // get string length in string1 and divide by 2
  EXPO *ex_array1 = malloc(string_size);
  EXPO *ex_array2 = malloc(string_size);
```

That way the memory allocated for ex_arrays will survive after the function returns, that way you can still access it in other functions.

Comment: "Surely it is possible to return an array of structs from a function. It works by returning a pointer" => soooo not an array, sooo it's not possible ;) Never say or vaguely say pointer == array, this is deeply wrong specially to a new coder. `struct array_s *ret = malloc(sizeof(struct array_s), 5);` this is not an array, but a contigus sequence of the same element. and by the way, this doesn't compile ;) you confuse with `calloc()`; `malloc(string_size);` and `malloc(string_size);` forget to count the nul terminate byte...

Comment: Why not, let us argue a bit ;) From [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) `Array is a type consisting of a contiguously allocated nonempty sequence of objects with a particular element type.`. Your point is correct, I return a pointer to contiguously allocated sequence of objects and not these objects them self. I can point out, that there are no arrays in C, only pointers. My intention was to show how it is done in "real" code. What if i wrap 5 arrays in a `struct ret_s { struct array_s a[5]; };` and return this struct, does this count as returning an array?

Comment: This count as returning a structure, not an array. And array exist in C, you give the proof yourself with your link, but "Array is a type consisting of a contiguously allocated nonempty sequence of objects with a particular element type." A => B, but common error is to suppose that B => A. a type consisting of a contiguously allocated nonempty sequence of objects with a particular element type is not always an array ;) (note that even C standard confuse array and pointer sometime...)

Comment: I would return a structure that contains that array... Anyway, I guess you are right, I will edit the answer and thank you for your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still struggling to understand everything, but I did change my ex_arrays to static, which seems to be working. I tried this first because it seemed the simplest solution, if I encounter any problems I will try to allocate space the way you suggested.